# Android: Smooth background colour repeating with boarder

Tags: android, border, background-color

i did the smooth background colour repeating for TextView like below

```
final Handler mHandler2 = new Handler();

        final Runnable mUpdateResults2 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(tvGoLive, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                colorFade.setDuration(1000);
                colorFade.start();

            }
        };

        final Runnable mUpdateResults3 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(tvGoLive, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.parseColor("#000000"), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                colorFade.setDuration(1000);
                colorFade.start();

            }
        };

        int delay2 = 1000;

        int period2 = 1000;

        Timer timer2 = new Timer();

        timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

       int rotation = 1;

        public void run() {

            if(rotation == 1){
                mHandler2.post(mUpdateResults2);
                rotation = 2;
            }else if (rotation == 2) {
                mHandler2.post(mUpdateResults3);
                rotation = 1;
            }
        }

        }, delay2, period2);
```

Now i need to set the boarder for this TextView programmatically. For this requirement i tried some codes in SO and Google, but i didn't get the boarder for text view. So, any one give me the code for setting boarder with  smooth background colour repeating

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution

**1. Drawable xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#0000FF" />


        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

If you need boarder, then add `<corners android:radius="5dp" />` inside shape of drawable xml

**2. Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_radious" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/club_detail_go_live_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_go_live_small"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**3. Code**

Code as above question